# How to get URL of model being serialized in Django REST Framework?

Tags: django, api, rest, serialization, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create an API using Django REST Framework that looks like this:

```
[
    "expression": {
        "expression": e, 
        "url": e_url
    },
    "definition": d
]
```

I am having problems retrieving the `url` field inside the `expression` object. I am trying to use `HyperlinkedRelatedField` but could not make it work. I want to point out that `url` is **NOT** a field in my `Expression` model.

```
class ExpressionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
        view_name="dictionary:expression",
        lookup_field="slug",
        read_only=True,
        many=False,
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Expression
        fields = ["url", "expression"]  

class DefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    expression = ExpressionSerializer(many=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Definition
        fields = ["expression", "definition"]
```

How can I retrieve the URL for expression?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `url` is not part of the `Expression` model, then you need to use `SerializerMethodField`:

```
url = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

def get_url(self, expression):
    return "url_goes_here"
```